# How to analyze inside a function

Tags: r, tidyverse

I am trying to look within the function 'tab1' of the 'table1' R package to see if I can customize a couple of things on a table. Getting the following error:

```
table1
function (x, ...) 
{
    UseMethod("table1")
}
<bytecode: 0x0000023376840aa0>
<environment: namespace:table1>

# I used as described above.
> UseMethod("table1")
Error in UseMethod("table1") : 
  'UseMethod' used in an inappropriate fashion
```

Comment: It's a generic function so use `methods(table1)` to see it's different versions. For me it lists `table1.default*` and `table1.formula*` where the `*` means they are unexpected. you can see them with `table1:::table1.default` (using triple colon).

Comment: Attached answer will be handy. Also check out [Advanced R - S3 methods](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/s3.html#s3-methods) for some walkthrough on how it works. Your function you want to look for is likely `table1.default` - if you run that it should give you the code.